# passing item.key from FlatList to Text component in react native

Tags: react-native

I'd like to have a FlatList with components that when clicked call a function called "scrollPressed". I have managed to make this work however I can't manage to pass the item's key to the function. My goal is for the scrollPressed function to behave differently depending on which item is pressed. Here is the code I have right now:

```
export default class Scroll extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {page: 1, thing: "unset"}
        this.scrollPressed = this.scrollPressed.bind(this)
    }

    scrollPressed(input){
        // do stuff
    }

    render(){
            return(
                <View style={{padding: 30}}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={[{key: 'a'},
                        {key: 'b'}
                        ]}
                      renderItem={({item}) => <Text onPress={({item}) => this.scrollPressed(item.key)}>{item.key}</Text>}
                    />
                </View>
            )
    }
}
```

The error I get is `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.key')`

from this I believe that item is undefined however I am able to use item.key at then of the line like so: `...{item.key}</Text>}` so I am confused as to why it is undefined in one case but not the other.

I'd like to know why it is undefined in one situation and not the other, also I'd like to know how to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: can you bind the function call like `this.scrollPressed.bind(this,item.key)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
renderItem={({item}) => <Text onPress={() => this.scrollPressed(item.key)}>{item.key}</Text>}
```

**Explanation:** Error because it trying to evaluate `item.key` an argument you passed to here `this.scrollPressed` but there is not `{item}`.

I don't know your idea behind `onPress={({item})`, basically onPress call back not hold any object named `item` and your trying to pass this `item` to `scrollPressed` so there is error (as there is no such `item`).

**Reference:** [Text onPress docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#onpress)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code, which will help you. Please try below code:

```
export default class Scroll extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {page: 1, thing: "unset"}
  }

  scrollPressed(input){
    // do stuff
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <View style={{padding: 30}}>
            <FlatList
                data={[{key: 'a'},{key: 'b'}]}
                renderItem={({item}) =>this.renderTextItem(item) }
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
        </View>
    )
  }

  renderTextItem(item){
    return(
        <Text
          onPress={() => this.scrollPressed(item.key)}>
          {item.key}
        </Text>
    )
  }
}
```